# Prove: $f(x)=e^{ax}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Am I being fooled by how simple this statement looks? My book is currently telling me to take both $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) =1$ and $f(x_1+x_2)=f(x_1)f(x_2)$ where $-\infty<x_1,x_2<\infty$, but I did not invoke either of these properties. I'm not really sure how to go about this other than your standard $\delta-\epsilon$ proof for continuity. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the properties $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$ and $f(x_1+x_2)=f(x_1)f(x_2)$ we have
$$\lim _{x\to x_0} e^{ax}= \lim_{h\to 0} e^{a(x_0+h)}= \lim_{h\to 0} (e^{ax_0}\cdot e^{ah})= e^{ax_0} \lim_{h\to 0} e^{ah}= e^{ax_0}$$

Comment: Thanks!! Haha I can't believe it was that easy!

Answer (score 1):

We can show it using definition. Consider $f(h+b) - f(b) = e^{a(h+b)} - e^{ab} = e^{ab}\left(e^{ah} - 1\right) \to 0$ when $h \to 0$, this means $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to b} f(x) = f(b)$, and $f$ is continuous at $b$, so it is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ since $b$ is any real number.